# Angular functions are performed twice when called in the html file

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I tried to start an angular project, I've created a simple component and  started a console.log in it but I have Confusing problem. when I calling a function in html file from ts file its run twice

TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-hello',
      templateUrl: './hello.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./hello.component.less']
    })
    export class HelloComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit(): void {
      }


      log(val)

      { 
        console.log(val);
       }



      test() {
        let time = new Date()
        console.log(time.getSeconds());

      }

    }
```

html :

hello works!

{{log('test')}}
 {{test()}}

image log:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tD1Q2.png)

Comment: please show you full html, and the containing component html too (if this one is not the root component)

Comment: this is full html component, just one </p>  tag:  <p>hello works! </p>
{{log('test')}}   {{test()}}

Comment: Show the html where you have `<app-hello></app-hello>`

Comment: this is what i meant, you can check the console : https://angular-nr6hz8.stackblitz.io

Comment: This is not a good link. Please send link to the stackblitz project to see the source code. The link you sent leads to a page that says: `Hello Angular!
Start editing to see some magic happen :)

Hello world!`

Comment: and its stackblitz :  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nr6hz8

Comment: Do you see this twice also on your own PC or only in stackblitz?

Comment: yes I did, I tested my local project in other computer and other browsers

Answer (score 0):

Where and how often do you call your component?
Can you produce a simple example on stackblitz?

Without any further info, we can just guess what it is.
You propably have called your component via '' twice.

Each instance will call all your template and hence its calling functions.

Comment: this is what i meant, you can check the console : https://angular-nr6hz8.stackblitz.io

Comment: and this is the code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nr6hz8